# How to say "Do you want to know?" in Japanese 尊敬語?

Tags: grammar, honorifics, keigo

In 尊敬語、we use 「ご存じですか。」to say "Do you know?".

Now, how do we say for asking 「知りたいでしょうか。」or "Do you want to know?" in Japanese 尊敬語?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most common way would be to say:

> 「お[知]{し}りになりたいですか。」

You could not use 「[存]{ぞん}じる」 to say this.

Comment: How about 「お知りになりたいでしょうか。」?

Comment: It's an expression that implies you doubt that the opponent want to know something.

Comment: do you want to be a butt?